# are there any nonparametric forecasting methods?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, forecasting, nonparametric

Are there any good statistical non-parametric forecasting methods besides machine learning methods like neural networks/decision trees etc. for time series analysis ?

If so, are there any R packages that implement them ?

Comment: How about non-parametric regression in the np package?

Comment: There are exponential smoothing methods that can be used for forecasting. time series. They can be shown to be equivalent to time series models in the ARIMA framework so some would argue that they are therefore parametric. But one can also regard  them as non-parametric if one uses them directly without estimating the equivalent underlying ARIMA model. There is simple ES, double ES and holt-winters ES. Each one makes  different assumptions about the mean, the trend and the seasonality.

Comment: @chandler Can you elaborate on how to implement them ?